# Create Accessible Partition by Windows and Linux

Tags: partition, dual-boot, ntfs, shared-partition

I plan to dual boot windows and kde neon on my laptop. Since I will be doing cross-platform development I would like my code to be accessible by both linux and windows, therefore, I want to create a separate partition and house my development there.

However, before I am not so sure this approach works. If I dual boot kde neon, will I be able to access a windows partition that is not the OS partition itself? As an example the D drvie (dev) below:
[image]

Additional Information:

The dev partition is formatted as NTFS

Comment: Microsoft file systems can be managed by Linux, but Linux file systems cannot be managed by Windows. So you can use FAT32, exFAT or NTFS for a data partition, common to both operating systems. I would suggest NTFS because it has journaling. - I would also suggest that you turn off Fast Startup in Windows. -- Fast Startup is a kind of semi-hibernation, and when Windows it shut down, it leaves file systems in dirty states (without proper flushing of buffers), and this causes problems for Linux (which does not want to write (opens read-only).

Comment: To add a small note to @sudodus comment, you may need to install third-party applications to enable NTFS or exFAT filesystems on certain Linux distributions.